# Why are columns overlapping?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Please look at this [example code](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//iprogramamos.com/iexplica/admin/movimentos.aspx&w=1024&h=600&s=1) to see my problem.
Here is part of my APT code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form runat="server">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1>
                Aluno! 
              </h1>
            </div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" PageSize="20" Width="263px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="nome" HeaderText="nome" SortExpression="nome" />
              </Columns>
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066FF" />
            </asp:GridView>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1>
                Disciplina!
              </h1>
            </div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" PageSize="20" Width="458px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="codigo" HeaderText="codigo" SortExpression="codigo" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="descricao" HeaderText="descricao" SortExpression="descricao" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="preco" HeaderText="Preço c/Iva" SortExpression="preco" />
              </Columns>
              <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#0066FF" />
            </asp:GridView>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1>
                Movimento!
              </h1>
            </div>
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="valopago">
                  Valor Pago
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="valorpago" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="datamovimento">
                  Data Pagamento
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="datamovimento" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="txtdescritivo">
                  Descritivo Pagamento
                </label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdescritivo" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
              </div>
              <br /> Aluno:
              <asp:Label ID="lblnumeroaluno" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
              <asp:Label ID="lblAluno" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
              <br /> Disciplina:
              <asp:Label ID="lblcodigodisciplina" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
              <asp:Label ID="lblDisciplina" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
              <br />
              <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Gravar" CssClass="btn btn-success form-control" OnClick="Gravar_Movimento" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me to understand why I am seeing this result? Why is the Movimento column overlapping the Disciplina column?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your rendered html (output) also.

Comment: Most people don't use ASP.net so most of us can't render your code and most of us, therefore, can't help you.

Comment: May I know which kind of screen did you use to display the output ?

Comment: Also by overlapping do you mean one of the column got move down to a newline but you want to display 3 columns in a row?

Comment: Hi on first line of my post there is a link (example code). If you follow this link you will  see the problem.

Comment: It's overlapping because you made the table inside of the Disciplina column wider than the available space through inline styling. Remove that width, and the layout is as expected.

Comment: Serlite You're absolutely right. Thank you. Please can you tell me how can I mark your answer as true, because I'm new here?